# Pass application context using ViewModel and ViewModel Provider Factory

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

This is the first time I am using MVVM and I want to do it right. I have this:

**LoginActivity**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: SettingsViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        val viewModelProviderFactory = SettingsViewModelProviderFactory()
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelProviderFactory).get(SettingsViewModel::class.java)

        bottomLoginNavigationView.setupWithNavController(loginNavHostFragment.findNavController())
    }
}
```

**SettingsViewModelFactory**

```
class SettingsViewModelProviderFactory() : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return SettingsViewModel() as T
    }
}
```

In my SettingsViewModel I need the application context. From what I have searched, I need to pass the application: Application in my constructor then inherit the AndroidViewModel like so:

```
class SettingsViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application)
{
  private val context = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext
}
```

If I do it like so, I get an error in my SettingsViewModelProviderFactory. I get the error in the `...return SettingsViewModel() as T` because I need to pass the application context as it is needed in the parameter of SettingsViewModel(application: Application).

Comment: You already have the application in the `SettingsViewModel` constructor. if you prefix that with `val` you should be able to access it directly

Comment: @IvanWooll I don't get it. Can you please show me how. I think your solution is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

In my LoginActivity, I added this

```
val application = requireNotNull(this).application
val viewModelProviderFactory = SettingsViewModelProviderFactory(application)
viewModel = ....
```

then in my SettingsViewModelProviderFactory, I added this

```
class SettingsViewModelProviderFactory(
    private val application: Application
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {...}
```